# Connect JSON in Javascript via field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to connect JSON data into my Javascript and the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "status":"ok",
  "count":5,
  "pages":1,
  "category":{
    "id":85,
    "slug":"front-page-active",
    "title":"Front Page Active",
    "description":"",
    "parent":0,
    "post_count":5
    },
  "posts":[{
      "id":1535,
      "type":"post",
      "slug":"url",
      "url":"url/",
      "status":"publish",
      "title":"title",
      "title_plain":"title",
      "content":"content… …
```

My Javscript looks like this:

```
'<p class="listTitle">' + item.title + '</p>'
```

I know I am connecting the file properly because I have gotten this to work with other JSON files. I am thinking that this file is setup differently and I just don't know what I am missing. Do I have to modify the 
    item.title
call?

This is the full javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outputNews = $('#newsPageUl');
    var spinner = $('.pageLoaderSpinner');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 20000,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var newsEvent = 

                //Generated HTML

                '<li><div class="newsFeedTopBg"></div><div class="newsFeedMidBg">'
                + '<p class="listTitle">' + item.title + '</p>'
                // + '<p class="date">' + item.posts[0].date + '</p>'
                // + '<p class="pContent">' + item.posts[0].content + '</p>'
                + '</div><div class="newsFeedBottomBg"></div></li>'

                //End Generated HTML

                ;

                spinner.empty();
                outputNews.append(newsEvent);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            spinner.empty();
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                "Could not connect.",
                connectionErrorNews,
                'Connection Error',
                "Go Back, Try Again"
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What is `item.title`? There seems to be no such variable/tree in your JSON?

Comment: But there are `item.category.title` and `item.posts[0].title`...

Comment: I tried both of those and nothing comes up. I knew my syntax was off. I don't know this too well... I want the content and title that is within the Posts section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN your JavaScript file you have the line:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){
```

Go ahead and change that to:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(i,item){
```

That will set your `item` variable to the post object of each post. And post has title, so everything should now work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 5,
    "pages": 1,
    "category": {
        "id": 85,
        "slug": "front-page-active",
        "title": "Front Page Active",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 0,
        "post_count": 5
    },
    "posts": [{
        "id": 1535,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "haverhill-public-schools-holiday-events-calendar",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.haverhill-ps.org\/haverhill-public-schools-holiday-events-calendar\/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Haverhill Public Schools holiday events calendar"
    }, {
        "id": 1536,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "haverhill-public-schools-holiday-events-calendar",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.haverhill-ps.org\/haverhill-public-schools-holiday-events-calendar\/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Haverhill Public Schools holiday events calendar"
    }]};

for(key in data) {
  if(key == "category")
      alert(data["category"].title);
  if(key == "posts")
      data["posts"].forEach(function(e) {
          alert(e.title);
      });
}
```

---

1. http://jsfiddle.net/3T7tC/2/